# Svn propget and propset

Tags: svn, ant

What is the actual process of `svn propget` and `svn propset`? How will it work and where we can use this? since im new to ant. so please any one give me detailed explanation.

Comment: How are svn properties related to ant?

Comment: I want to use these properties in build process, where i have used the ant script.

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess that you've specified [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) tag because your task is to run `svn propget` and `svn propset` from ant build job. If you want to learn how to configure and operate with ant, see its documentation, [Apache Ant™ Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/).
2. To learn about Subversion properties, see [SVNBook | Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html) and

   - [`svn propget`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propget.html)
   - [`svn propset`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html)
   - [`svn proplist`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.proplist.html)
   - [`svn propdel`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propdel.html)
   - [`svn propedit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propedit.html)